# proper glue for reattaching windshield molding

Tags: windshield-molding

I am looking for the best glue to reattach some windshield molding that started peeling away in some 100+ deg weather last year. Since then and recently I have removed the top and sides, cleaned out the channels of dirt and rust, and rusty metal primed everything. The first glue tried was [3M 08008 Black Super Weatherstrip Adhesive](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00063X38M/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1) but it was super difficult to use, and although I got one side done, it seems too securely attached.

As such I am looking for another glue to attach the other two sides that is not quite as strong because windshields eventually need replacing and would hope the molding is not destroyed in the process. Talking to glass installers, I have found two that are urethane based: [Dow U-418 Auto Glass Sealant](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0182RGDP8) and [Sikaflex 220+ Fast Curing Urethane Adhesive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002CXGUX4). Here is one more that is silicone based: [Surebond High-Temp Silicone Sealant](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007IBN0LA).

Since it is just the molding glued on the surface and not also under the glass, it seems like some of these glues are more than is needed, but any thoughts on the best type of glue for this application?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Shopping questions are off-topic here as they go out of date too quickly, so I've made a small edit to your post to make it about the type of glue to use rather than a particular brand.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a proper windscreen bonding adhesive, as these are designed for exactly the situation you're describing. From what I understand they remain slightly soft, making it easier to remove them later if you need to change the windscreen.

If you know any installers, ask them nicely to do it for you, it will probably be cheaper than buying a full pack of the glue!